# How should "to + verb + to + verb" be interpreted?

Tags: meaning

> Do not attempt to adjust, repair, or try to fix the device.

I think it's somewhat ambiguous. Which interpretation is correct for the example above?

> Do not attempt to adjust to fix the device.
>
> Do not attempt to modify to fix the device.
>
> Do not attempt to try to fix the device. or  Do not try to fix the
>   device. (which one is correct among two?)

Or

> Do not attempt to adjust the device.
>
> Do not attempt to modify the device.
>
> Do not attempt to try to fix the device.

Comment: This is a redundant sentence. "attempt" and "try" are synonyms, and "repair" and "fix" are also synonyms. I think whoever wrote this sentence didn't proofread... it's not a good sentence. "Do not attempt to adjust or repair the device" would make more sense. Otherwise you'd be saying essentially, "Do not attempt to adjust the device, attempt to repair the device, or attempt to attempt to repair the device." (!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that warning is ambiguous. But it is certainly redundant. "Try to fix" means the same as "attempt to repair," which was already covered earlier in the sentence.

I think the writer of that statement really wanted to get the point across. He wrote the first part in a style he thought a lawyer might appreciate, but then he decided to repeat it in what he thought was "plain language" so everyone would get it, even the simple doofuses that he regards as his customer base.